# Laravel not persisting file from view to controller using forms

Tags: laravel, file, view, controller

I have a problem with storing an image using Laravel 5.1. I know Laravel has 5.6, so that's that.

Here is my form: for comparison; right one works and left one does not work.

[Form elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKgcC.png)

[image]

I have also checked that the form ends appropriately.

Here is my controller method and where I get soon introduced return value.

[Controller method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsdYk.png)

[image]

Here is request going from view to Controller:

[Request Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOnvC.png)

[image]

EDIT #1: I redid everything on a newly made controller, and now everything works. I copied everything from old (this) controller. I have no idea what the problem was, but I noticed that the file is shown as empty in other controllers aswell if accessed via $request->all(). before the logic didn't go inside the if statement if(file = $request->file('file)) and I thought it didn't get the data, but it might be that the server did not update itself for some reason and I updated things too fast.

Thank you everyone for trying to help. :)

Comment: Why  are you returning before saving in line number 26. You need to return $input after if condition then you can see the all data

Comment: Copy and paste your code instead adding an image please

Comment: By the way your code looks, you could also check if any `News` is saved to the db, i have a feeling you forgot that return statement on line 26 ;)

Comment: Mahesh and Slow: Because if you looked the request value, you can see that news_file{} is empty object. That's why I am returning it at the moment.

Comment: And yes, because I am not validating the request at the moment, if I take the return statement off, it will save form data to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redid everything on a newly made controller, and now everything works. I copied everything from old (this) controller. I have no idea what the problem was, but I noticed that the file is shown as empty in other controllers aswell if accessed via $request->all().

before the logic didn't go inside the if statement if(file = $request->file('file)) and I thought it didn't get the data, but it might be that the server did not update itself for some reason and I updated things too fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no permission rights to write in that folder, can you try this?

`chmod -R 755 public/images`

Comment: I have another Controller with what I am able to add files to that same folder.